# Process Builder Screen blank

Tags: flow, process-builder

I've been trying to update an existing inactive process with about 250 criteria and then of course 250 corresponding actions. Every time I've tried to access this particular process in the last 15 hours, I get a blank screen. Any ideas what the problem could be?

I have a clone of the exact same process that's running with any issues. I've also been able to create new (shorter) processes in the meantime without any issues. Not sure what to do here.

Comment: better to raise a case with salesforce to see if they can check the issue on their side as well

Comment: Thanks Vamsi! I did do that, but I thought I would check here as well to see if anyone had run into the issue before. Trying to cover all the bases!